# A C++11 based signals/slots with ordering

Tags: user-interface, c++11, signals-slots

I may be a bit in over my head here, but if you never try new things - you'll never learn I suppose. I'm working with some multi-touch stuff and have built myself a small but functional GUI library. Up until now I've been used boosts Signals2 library to have my detected gestures be distributed to all active GUI elements (whether on screen or not). I'm a big fan of avoiding pre-mature optimization, so things have been honky-dory until now.

I've used vs2013's profiler to find out that when the user goes touch crazy (the device supports up to 41 simultaneous touches), then my system grinds to a halt, and Signals2 is the culprit. Keep in mind that each touch can trigger a number of Gestures which are all communicated to every GUI element that have registered to interact with this type of Gesture.

Now there are a number of ways to deal with this bottleneck:

1. Have GUI elements work more cleverly and disconnect them when they're off-screen.
2. Optimize the signals/slots system so the calls are resolved faster.
3. Prioritization of events.

I'm not a big fan of ever having to deal with 3 - if avoidable - as it'll directly impact the responsiveness of my application. Nr. 1 should probably be implemented, but I'm more interested in getting to Nr. 2 first.

I don't really need any big fancy stuff. The Signals/Slots system I'd need really only needs to do the core emission stuff along with these 2 feature:

- Slots must be able to return a value ending the emission - effectively cancelling any subsequent handling of a signal.
- Slots must be order-able - and fairly efficient at this. GUI elements that are interacted with will pop-up above others, so this type of change in order is bound to happen quite often.

I stumbled across this really interesting implementation

https://testbit.eu/2013/cpp11-signal-system-performance/

which seems to have everything except the 'ordering' I need. I've only looked over the code once, and it does seem a little intimidating. If I were to try and add ordering capabilities, I'd prefer not to change too much stuff around if necessary. Does anyone have experience with this stuff? I'm fairly certain that a linked list is not optimal for constant removal and insertion, but then again, it probably needs to be optimized the most for constant emission calls.

Any thoughts are most welcome!

**--- Update ---**

I've spend a little time adding the features I needed to the code put into the public domain above and pasted the complete (and somewhat hacky version) here:

[SimpleSignal with added features](http://codepad.org/Lo6yj0Eh)

In short, I've added:

- Blockable Connections (Implemented via simple IF statement)
- Depth/Order parameter (Linear-search insertion)

With those additions, keep in mind it has these current issues:

- Blocked connections are simply skipped, not actively removed from the data-structure, so having a lot of blocked connections will affect run-time performance.
- Depth is only maintained during insertion. So if you'd like to change the depth you'll have to disconnect and reconnect your slot.
- Since the SignalLink interface has become exposed (as a result of my block implementation), it's less safe from a user perspective. It's way easier for you to shoot yourself in the foot with this version by messing with existing references and pointers.
- This implementation hasn't been as thoroughly tested as the original I'm sure. I did try out the new functionality a bit. User beware.

Comment: I've had a closer look at Signals2 included in boost and if I'm not mistaken, it looks to me as though they also utilize a double-linked list as their data structure for managing callbacks. However, they also employ a tree-structure for maintaining order.

Comment: I too was in need of something simpler than boost's, and [wrote my own signals library](https://bitbucket.org/danielko/simplesignal/src/45f7b4411822ff4e631574b3213c52d822f9a4c5/include/SimpleSignal%2B%2B.hpp?at=default). You can stop a triggered signal by calling the `Signal::stop()` method. Connections can be ordered only at slot construction, but it would be trivial to define a dynamic ordering. Connections are stored in vectors, the assumption being you will only have a couple of slots per signal.